# TXT file to char array and char array to TXT file

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I'm new to C++ and wanted to do the following thing: consider a txt file that looks like this for example:

```
+-+-+-+-+
+-+-o-+-o
+-o-+-+-+
+-+-+-+-+
```

Now I want to take the content of this file and copy it into an array of the same size and do the other thing around aswell. Thank you for your help, explaining your answer would be extra amazing :)

Comment: SO is not a code writing forum. **Describe the problem you are having, what your understanding of the problem is and where you are confused**. Adding some code would be extra amazing

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using build-in arrays for variable sized things is a bit tricky. The easy way is to use a suitable `std::vector<char>` instead:

```
std::ifstream in(from_filename);
std::vector<char> array{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in),
                        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};

// ...
std::ofstream out(to_filename);
std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(),
          std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));
```

Comment: Well seems rather easy, once you know what to do, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do you possibly also know whether or not there is a restriction of 1024 chars while using std::copy(array.begin(), array.end, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out)); to copy the content of the array into my file? It does seem like that and I haven't found something about that so far. 2048 would be more than enough I guess

Comment: There is no limit on the characters which can be written. If you want to limit the number of characters you need to limit the source.